# "If he were to be selected, I would be very happy"

Tags: sentence-construction, conditional-constructions, conditionals

I know if I say "If it were to rain, it would be a pleasant day". = If it rained, it would be a pleasant day".

But my query is if I say, **"If he were to be selected, I would be very happy".**

Does it is equivalent to **"If he had to be selected, I would be very happy" or "If someone selected him", I would be very happy".**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, "*If he were to be selected, I would be very happy*" is good grammar, and yes, it means the same as, "*If someone selected him", I would be very happy*".

It does not mean the same as, "*If he **had to** be selected, I would be very happy*". There is no meaning of requirement in the original sentence, so "have to" has the wrong meaning.

Answer (score 1):

This is the "second conditional",  the condition "he were to be selected" refers to a hypothetical future state that is seen as unlikely.  So it means roughly "If someone selects him (though I don't think anyone will select him)..."